# Unable to Elaborate FIFO on SP601

Tags: vhdl, fifo

I'm trying to generate a FIFO from the Xilinx Core generator.

It has a common clock with block RAM, it's a standard FIFO, 2 bits wide and 16 deep.

I've made a test bench based on the core:

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.ALL;

library unisim;
use unisim.VComponents.all;


ENTITY fifo_test IS
END fifo_test;

ARCHITECTURE behavior OF fifo_test IS 

    -- Component Declaration for the Unit Under Test (UUT)

    COMPONENT fifo_generator_v9_3
    PORT(
         clk : IN  std_logic;
         rst : IN  std_logic;
         din : IN  std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
         wr_en : IN  std_logic;
         rd_en : IN  std_logic;
         dout : OUT  std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
         full : OUT  std_logic;
         empty : OUT  std_logic
        );
    END COMPONENT;


   --Inputs
   signal clk : std_logic := '0';
   signal rst : std_logic := '0';
   signal din : std_logic_vector(1 downto 0) := (others => '0');
   signal wr_en : std_logic := '1';
   signal rd_en : std_logic := '1';

    --Outputs
   signal dout : std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
   signal full : std_logic;
   signal empty : std_logic;

   -- Clock period definitions
   constant clk_period : time := 10 ns;

BEGIN

    -- Instantiate the Unit Under Test (UUT)
   uut: fifo_generator_v9_3 PORT MAP (
          clk => clk,
          rst => rst,
          din => din,
          wr_en => wr_en,
          rd_en => rd_en,
          dout => dout,
          full => full,
          empty => empty
        );

   -- Clock process definitions
   clk_process :process
   begin
        clk <= '0';
        wait for clk_period/2;
        clk <= '1';
        wait for clk_period/2;
   end process;


   -- Stimulus process
   stim_proc: process
   begin        
      -- hold reset state for 100 ns.
      wait for 100 ns;  

      wait for clk_period*10;

      -- insert stimulus here 

      wait;
   end process;

END;
```

Here is what the file looks like in ISE:

[image: Test Bench]

The error I get:

```
ERROR:Simulator:793 - Unable to elaborate instantiated module FIFO_GENERATOR_V9_3

Process "Simulate Behavioral Model" failed
```

Why does this fail?

Answer (score 1):

Coregen will also output a .vhd file for the FIFO you created.  You need this .vhd file to be in the modelsim project that you are using.  fifo_generator_v9_3.vhd.

Comment: Cheers, this is the first time I'm using a core generator - I thought you could just use the .xco file. I'm guessing for the real project, I won't need to .vhd file?

Comment: This is true, you do not need the .vhd file to synthesize and build your FPGA.  I don't know why Xilinx changed the behavior of FIFOs.  You used to be able to just instantiate them, but now you have to go through coregen, which is phenomenally infuriating.  Does anyone know why they made this change?

Comment: Still didn't work. If I just create my owwn .vhd FIFO, this might be easier/quicker.

I've added the edited picture above